Apache Nifi: update timezone in Record
The source csv file is:
"date_time"
"2024-07-30 19:59:04"

The timezone in fact is GMT+3
I use UpdateRecord with following properties:
Replacement Value Strategy  -> Literal Value
/new_dt                     -> ${date_time.value:toDate():toNumber():minus(3600).format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "GMT")}

Expected output is:
"new_dt"
"2024-07-30 16:59:04"

but nothing is changed:
"new_dt"
"2024-07-30 19:59:04"


Use an UpdateRecord:

Replacement Value Strategy: Record Path Value
/new_dt: format( toDate( /date_time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "GMT+3:00"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "GMT")

input
"date_time"
"2024-07-30 19:59:04"

output
date_time;new_dt
2024-07-30 19:59:04;2024-07-30 16:59:04

